# Htaccess redirect with parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a `.htaccess` redirect with a parameter but it's not working. Seems like my regex are also wrong. :(

```
Original URL 1: http://www.example.com/?team=john-doe 
Original URL 2: http://www.example.com/?team

Target URL: http://www.example.com/company/
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} team=john-doe
RewriteRule /company/ [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found a generator that works perfectly: 
https://donatstudios.com/RewriteRule_Generator

```
# 301 --- http://www.example.com/?team=john-doe => http://www.example.com/company/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)team\=john\-doe($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /company/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Although this does not appear to match your URL#2 (`http://www.example.com/?team`)? Minor point, but the `=` and `-` don't need to be escaped in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` is malformed, you are missing a *pattern* (first argument). Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^team(?:=john-doe)?
RewriteRule ^$ /company/? [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` matches requests for the domain root. The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* strips the query string from the redirected URL (on Apache 2.4+ you can use the `QSD` flag instead).

The *CondPattern* `^team(?:=john-doe)?` matches either "team=john-doe" (URL#1) or "team" (URL#2) at the start of the query string. The `(?:` part just makes it non-capturing.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.